# error on update the state of textStyle after upgrade to 3.7.0

Tags: flutter, dart

after upgrade the flutter from `3.3.10` to `3.7.0` this error start appear after change the state of `textStyle` of `Material` widget:

> Failed to interpolate TextStyles with different inherit values.

there is a simple exemple:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool state = false;

  void _changeState() {
    setState(() {
      state = !state;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Material(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
          elevation: 2,
          textStyle: !state ? const TextStyle(color: Color(0xff4c4c4c)) : null,
          child: const Text('Click me')
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _changeState,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because, when you toggle the state of the `textStyle` property, it's going from `null` to a `TextStyle object`. Because null does not have any inherit property, it's trying to interpolate between two different inherit values, which is not possible.

Try to provide `default text style` for the `Material` widget so that it will always have a textstyle to inherit from.

```
Material(
    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
    elevation: 2,
    textStyle: !state && Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1 != null
        ? Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium.copyWith(color: Color(0xff4c4c4c))
        : Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
    child: const Text('Click me')
);
```

Comment: in the version 3.7.0 `subtitle1` is depricated and is nullable

Comment: I apologize for overlooking that, i have updated my code to contain `bodyText1`. Hope it helps

Comment: `bodyText1` too is depricated in 3.7.0, i think `bodyMedium` it be good

Comment: Oh i am sorry, i guess i am not running updated version of flutter v3.7.0

Comment: Use `bodyMedium` does it solves your error?